# Can I automatically run a command in webstorm after pushing to GitHub?

Tags: github, webstorm

Say I have a webstorm project. Every time I commit and **push** to github, I want WebStorm to run a certain command. I have searched on the internet on how to do this, but I can't figure it out. How can I do it? Or am I stuck with using webhooks?

Comment: Under `certain command` you mean Git command or WebStorm action ? Please clarify

Comment: @AntonDozortsev I mean any command you can run in a terminal, for example `ls`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately WebStorm don't provide any configuration for this workflow.

But still I will try to help you.

#### First

You can create bash instance and easily <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> run it using [BashSupport](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4230?pr=idea) plugin.

#### Second

Create instance of [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/external-tools.html) then assign any shortcut on it and also easily perform your often action. Examples:

- [Is there a way to connect Intellij IDEA to Sublime Text on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16130586/2650174)
- [IntelliJ IDEA 11: Running a shell script as a Run/Debug Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20105293/2650174)